# MySQL - How to modify column default value?

Tags: mysql, sql, default, alter

How do I change my column's default value from None to something else? For example, I want my dates to have a default value of 0000-00-00 if I don't specify one when I create the row.

I understand this in phpMyAdmin, but I'm not sure how to do it via command prompt.

I also understand how to do this when adding a column. But all of my columns are made and have data in some of them.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN foo INT DEFAULT 0;
```

From searching, I found this line, but I'm not sure if that's what I want?

```
ALTER TABLE foobar_data MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';
```

Comment: what is your previous column type?

Comment: I'm trying to modify DATE and INT columns.

Comment: Careful about the `0000-00-00` as that is not within the valid date range. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use **ALTER TABLE** to **CHANGE** or **MODIFY** the **DEFAULT** value of column. Check this link [**ALTER TABLE SYNTAX**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` CHANGE `columnName` `columnName` DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00'; 
ALTER TABLE `tableName` MODIFY `columnName` DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00';
```

Comment: Will this apply 0000-00-00 to all my old rows that currently have None, or do I need to run a query to change those?

Comment: @macdonjo It will apply `0000-00-00` to all rows where the field is `null` in your column.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ALTER TABLE foobar_data CHANGE COLUMN col VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';
```

user CHANGE to alter a existing column

see [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `col_name` `col_name_again` VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'anydefault_text';
```

Hope it helps you too.