# How to reset a column to its default value in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

To reset a column value to its default, the following SQL statement can be used:

```
update "<table>"
set "<column>" = default
where "<condition>"
```

However, I couldn't find how to get the same query with SQLAlchemy. It can be taken from column's definition, but the idea is to get a query as above.

```
Table.column.default  # ColumnDefault object
```

Comment: I'm not expert in postgresql ..but is not just a update?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759462/updating-column-to-the-default-value-using-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a column value to its default just update it's value to text('default').

Check below:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
session.query(Table).filter(filter_conditions).update({column_name: sa.text('default')}, synchronize_session=False)

# Above line will produce the following query
query="update table_name set column_name=default where filter_conditions;"
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need!